# '[Errno 2] No such file or directory' error when installing Basemap

Tags: python, installation, package, matplotlib-basemap

I am using Spyder as part of Anaconda. When trying to install the package 'Basemap', the following error is returned:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\BASINS42\bin\PROJ_NAD\epsg'

For context, BASINS is a GIS-based environmental modelling software which I recently deleted. Not sure why Python thinks it's relevant.

I would like to successfully install the python Basemap package.

In the Anaconda Prompt, I have typed 'conda install basemap', and the prompt replies: 'All requested packages already installed'

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly understand the question but I assume you need hi-resolution basemap data. This is not contained in `Basemap` by default. You need to install `mpl_toolkits` separately in your conda environment with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```

See also [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/basemap-data-hires).

After doing this, executing

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

from python console should work normally.